# Vertical align flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, alignment, vertical-alignment

Product cards should be displayed as at https://www.mvideo.ru/komputernaya-tehnika-4107/monobloki-181/f/category=monobloki-603?reff=menu_main. But displayed as in the picture below

[image: Flex align]

Here is the code that displays the product cards

```js
        // такой же код, что и код выше - только для черных пунктов меню типа Моноблоки 
        let categoryflag='';
            $('.submenu__title a').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log('Inner check');             
                categoryflag=event.target.innerHTML;
                subcategoryflag=categoryflag;
                console.log(categoryflag);
                $.ajax ({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '../php/ajaxsubcategory1.php',
                    cache: false,                   
                    data: {categoryflag: categoryflag, subcategoryflag: subcategoryflag},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    complete: function(data) {
                        console.log(data.header);
                        console.log(data.countrecords);
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('check');
                        console.log(data);
                        $('.rightmenu').html(data.result.msg);
                        let centeroutput='<div id=\"topcenterarea\">'+'<h1>'+data.result.header+' '+data.result.countrecords+' товара' + data.output[0]['screendiagonal'] + '</h1>'+'</div>';
                        
                        
                        productcardsoutput='';
                        // productcard='<div class="ProductCardBlock">';
                        
                        
                        for (let i=0; i<data.result.countrecords; i++)
                            {
                                productcard='<div class="ProductCardBlock">';
                                productcard+='<div class="dynamic ProductImage">';
                                productcard+='<div id="ImageWrapper">';
                                productcard+='<img class="ProductPicture" src='+'"../images/'+data.output[i]['imagepath']+'">';
                                productcard+='</div>';
                                productcard+='</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="dynamic ProductDescription">';
                                productcard+='<div class="ProductName">' + data.output[i]['monoblockname'] +', ' + data.output[i]['color']+ '</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="ProductScreenParams">'+ '<div class="text">' + 'Диагональ/разрешение  ' + '</div>' + data.output[i]['screendiagonal'] + '/' + data.output[i]['resolution'] + 'пикс.' +'</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="ProductCpuType">'+ '<div class="text">' + 'Тип процессора  ' + '</div>' + data.output[i]['cputype'] +'</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="ProductCpuFrequency">'+ '<div class="text">'+ 'Частота процессора  ' +'</div>'+ data.output[i]['frequency'] +'</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="ProductRAM">' + '<div class="text">' + 'Оперативная память (RAM)  ' + '</div>' + data.output[i]['ramsize']  +'</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="ProductVideoCard">' + '<div class="text">'+'Графический контроллер  '+'</div>' + data.output[i]['videocard']  +'</div>'
                                
                                if (data.output[i]['memorytype']=='SSD') {
                                    productcard+='<div class="ProductDisksAndDrives">' + '<div class="text">' + 'Объем SSD  ' + '</div>' + data.output[i]['sizememorydata']  +'</div>';
                                }
                                else if (data.output[i]['memorytype']=='HDD') {
                                    productcard+='<div class="ProductDisksAndDrives">' + '<div class="text">' + 'Объем HDD  ' + '</div>' + data.output[i]['sizememorydata']  +'</div>';
                                };
                                
                                productcard+='</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="dynamic ProductBuyPart">'+ '<button type="submit" class="ProductAddToBasket" value="В корзину"></button>' +'</div>';
                                // productcard+='<div class="ProductScreenParams">'+ 'Диагональ/разрешение ' + data.output[i]['screendiagonal'] + '/' + data.output[i]['resolution'] + 'пикс.' +'</div>';
                                
                                
                                // productcard+='</div>';
                                // productcard+='</div>';
                                // productcard+='</div>';
                                // productcard+='</div>';
                                productcard+='</div>';
                                productcardsoutput+=productcard;
                            }
                        
                        centeroutput+=productcardsoutput;
                        
                        /*$('.centerarea').html('<div id=\"topcenterarea\">'+'<h1>'+data.header+' '+data.countrecords+' товара'+'</h1>'+'</div>');*/ 
                        $('.centerarea').html(centeroutput);

                        //expandCollapsedFunction();
                }
            }
            );
        }
        );
```

```css
.text {
    font: 12px Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
}

.ProductCardBlock {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: stretch;
    height: 168px;
    /*position: relative;*/
}

.ProductCardBlock .ProductImage {
    /*width: calc(191.5/931.75)*100%;*/
    /*width: 20%;*/
    height: 100%;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    width: 220px;
}

.ProductCardBlock .ProductImage #ImageWrapper .ProductPicture {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
}

.ProductCardBlock .ProductDescription {
    /*width: 70%;*/
    margin-top: 20px;
    font: 14px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*flex: 6;*/
}

.ProductCardBlock .ProductDescription .ProductName {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font: 16px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial,sans-serif;
    /*position: absolute;*/
}

.ProductCardBlock .ProductDescription .ProductScreenParams {
    font: 14px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial,sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;
    /*position: absolute;*/
}

.ProductCardBlock .ProductDescription .ProductCpuType {
    font: 14px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial,sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;  
    /*position: absolute;*/
}

.ProductCardBlock .ProductDescription .ProductCpuFrequency {
    font: 14px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial,sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;  
    /*position: absolute;*/
}

.ProductCardBlock .ProductDescription .ProductRAM {
    font: 14px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial,sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;  
    /*position: absolute;*/
}

.ProductCardBlock .ProductDescription .ProductVideoCard {
    font: 14px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial,sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;  
    /*position: absolute;*/
}

.ProductCardBlock .ProductDescription .ProductDisksAndDrives {
    font: 14px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial,sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;  
    /*position: absolute;*/
}

/*.ProductCardBlock */.ProductBuyPart {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding-top: auto;
    padding-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: 40px;
    /*margin-left: 40px;*/
    /*padding-right: 40px;*/
    /*width: 10%;*/
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*display: block;*/
    /*flex: 4;*/
    /*width: auto;*/
}

/*.ProductCardBlock .ProductBuyPart */.ProductAddToBasket {
    /*margin: auto;
    padding: auto;*/
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

Tell me how to achieve the desired alignment. Here is the code for easy editing https://jsfiddle.net/vladdvin/dzm7purk/2/.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-direction: column;`Instead of `flex-direction:row;` in your `.ProductCardBlock`.

Comment: An error in the location of product characteristics in `.ProductDescription` - the fact that the value of the product characteristic is lower than the name of the characteristic (see screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

use `display:flex` on the parent container and use
`justify-content:space-evenly`
or any other styling style you wish to align the children according to way you want
check out this example from [code-pen](https://codepen.io/jay-dev/pen/VwbvVoa?editors=1100)

Comment: An error in the location of product characteristics in `.ProductDescription` - the fact that the value of the product characteristic is lower than the name of the characteristic (see screenshot).